# Scripting Language for Java and its uses?

Tags: java, scripting

So I am going to work on a Java game and recently my friend suggested I use a scripting language to help development go smoother/faster.

so far I used XML as data storage and to make the HUD/UI but he recommended I learn Ruby, Python, Groovy, and/or Lua.

he Strongly recommended Lua for the same thing i use XML for.

basically what my question is :

What are scripting languages, what are they for,, should I use a scripting language, whats the difference between said scripting languages and XML, and which one should I learn and use for my java game?

Comment: The duplicate addresses many of your questions. Which scripting language to use for your game is a question that's off topic for this site.